# Gradle run showing this error "Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Hadoop home directory C:hadoopbin is not an absolute path."

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am trying to set up Gradle on Intellij and I keep getting this error when I run the program, It seems like the error is caused because of HADOOP_HOME path, I have tried using this but the error persists.

```
export HADOOP_HOME=hadoop


export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
```

I don't have have local admin access to this system so I am trying to set up the path using Gitbash and I am a beginner in Spark.

Comment: If you say you're using Linux, why does the error have `C:`?

Comment: C is the drive where I am setting the path.

Comment: Sure, but if you are "using Linux" (or Git Bash), it's not accessible that way, it should only be `/c/`. However, you should ideally be using WSL2, not Git bash

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the error - Hadoop home should be an absolute path. `export HADOOP_HOME=hadoop` is just relative. You need to make it absolute, for example:

```
export HADOOP_HOME=C:\hadoop
```

Comment: I am seeing both the old as well as the new PATH there, what command should I use if I want to remove the wrong env path?

Comment: If you're using Windows then you can modify environment variables via a GUI - https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html.